# How to pass ui-sref url to ng-click function

Tags: angularjs

```
<td class="text-left">
  <a class="curosr" ui-sref="private.Registered_details ({uid: 
   x.userID,vid:x.vehicleID,page_value:'page1'})" ng-
   click="linkClick(x.name,0,Registered_details/uid/vid/page_value)">{{x.name}}
  </a>
</td>
```

In the above code segment, I have a  with ui-sref="private.Registered_details ({uid: 
   x.userID,vid:x.vehicleID,page_value:'page1'})"..How to pass this a s url to linkClick funtion in ng-click

Comment: could you please tel me how to use in the existing code

Comment: what do you mean by passing url to `ng-click`? what do you want to achieve by that?

Comment: On click of the td i want to go that state at any point of time

Comment: did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Have `ng-click` like this. Pass all the details necessary to navigate to your chosen state.

```
<td class="text-left">
  <a class="curosr" ng-click="navigateToDetails(x)">{{x.name}}
  </a>
</td>
```

And in controller, first inject `$state` as dependency, and then, use [`$state.go`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options) to navigate to the state.

```
$scope.navigateToDetails = function(x) {
  // some amazing code to decide whether or not to navigate
  $state.go("private.Registered_details", {
    uid: x.userID,
    vid: x.vehicleID,
    page_value:'page1'
  });
}
```

Comment: It's one or the other: ui-sref, or an ng-click linked to a method in the controller.